# Scrapy - Use CSS to find elements that might contain differing subelements

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape https://www.hillhappenings.com/ for a number of data fields related to political events: name, time, data, and location.  I realized the HTML for the location field uses two different formats:

```
<li class="eventlist-meta-item eventlist-meta-address event-meta-item">
    2168 Rayburn House Office Building
</li>
```

...and ...

```
<li class="eventlist-meta-item eventlist-meta-address event-meta-item">            
    <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">A St.</span>
    <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">Washington, DC, 20002</span>
    <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">United States</span>
</li>
```

I'm using the following code to get the event titles and locations:

```
events = Selector(response=response).css('div.eventlist-column-info a.eventlist-title-link::text').getall()
addresses = Selector(response=response).css('div.eventlist-column-info li.eventlist-meta-item.eventlist-meta-address::text').getall()
```

The problem is, out of 80 events, 76 use format #1 and 4 use format #2 so I get 80 events but only 76 addresses.  I would like to be able to get the multiline addresses that use format #2 above in a single line like format #1.  I'm new to Scrapy as of this morning and am wondering: **"How can I use Scrapy to find address elements that have a span tag underneath of them so I can combine them into a single-line address?"**.

Comment: Did you try `addresses = ' '.join(Selector(...).css('... .eventlist-meta-address-line::text').getall())`?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  'join' doesn't actually quite accomplish what I need.  Let me see if I can explain the problem a little better.  When I do the getall() to get the addresses, I am missing the addresses that are in format #2 above because those addresses are inside of a span tag unlike in format #1.  My questions is: can I dynamically scrape elements based on whether or not they contain the <span> subelement?

Comment: Ah I see. See my answer

Comment: Hmm you mean `def my_func(a_param: param_type) -> return_type:`? It's called type annotation, mainly to help editors/IDEs for code autocompletion. You could just remove it, of course, it doesn't have any effect on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try attribute `[attr]` or wildcard selectors `*`? Since both formats contain text in an element with class `eventlist-meta-address-*`, you can use `[class*="eventlist-meta-address"]::text` or just `.eventlist-meta-address *::text`

```py
from parsel import Selector

def extract_address(sel: Selector) -> str:
    # this one works too
    # metas = s.css('.eventlist-meta-address *::text').getall()
    metas = s.css('[class*="eventlist-meta-address"]::text').getall()
    return ' '.join(m.strip() for m in metas if m.strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    format1 = '''
    <li class="eventlist-meta-item eventlist-meta-address event-meta-item">
        2168 Rayburn House Office Building
    </li>
    '''
    format2 = '''
    <li class="eventlist-meta-item eventlist-meta-address event-meta-item">
        <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">A St.</span>
        <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">Washington, DC, 20002</span>
        <span class="eventlist-meta-address-line">United States</span>
    </li>
    '''
    for f in [format1, format2]:
        s = Selector(f)
        print(extract_address(s))
```

output:

```
2168 Rayburn House Office Building
A St. Washington, DC, 20002 United States
```